# How can form a code string with data inserted in other rows in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, phpmyadmin, netbeans-7

i have a table items with column

description_Code:id,name and type

now i want form string code by selecting the first alphabet from each column

example:1,Car,bmw.
code result should should be 1cb.

Am using java in Netbean with Phpmyadmin,s MySql
pleaase help me

Comment: are you retrieving the results in java yet? Is question directed at SQL or Java?

Comment: what about 100,Car,Bentley still 1cb. Why not 1Cb as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: select * from table and store it in a result set. Say myRS
Step 2: myRS.getString("id")
Step 3: concatenate this string to required string which is initialy empty
step 4: myRS.getString("name");
Again do step 3

Do similary in a loop if you want such strings for all rows

**EDIT:**

add a key listener to all the input text fields (done by netbeans)
for example,

```
jTextField1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt){
        setTheField();
        }
    });
```

Then define,

```
private void setTheField(){
    char[] temp = new char[3];
    String id=jTextField1.getText();
    if(id.length()>0);
        temp[0]=id.charAt(0);
    String name=jTextField2.getText();
    if(name.length()>0);
        temp[1]=name.charAt(0);
    String type=jTextField3.getText();
    if(type.length()>0);
        temp[2]=type.charAt(0);
    jTextField4.setText(new String(temp)); //Output text Field
}
```

Now whenever any thing is typed, the last textField is set.
I hope this is what you excpected.

Comment: what if i want to it to automatically form the string code immediately i type name and type. i want it to appear in a different Jtextfield.i hope u get what am saying?

Comment: Actually I donot. Please explain your requirement in detail. Do you want it to happen in java itself? Or does mysql have a role ?

Comment: it should pick the data as you input them. Example as i input Bank it should automatically pick the 'B' into another JTextfeild. i hope u get it now

Comment: please am really new at programming so please explain your code. first of all how do i setTheField();. and please i will appreciate it if you added a sample code of the step 1 and 2. Thank You